# Can't Join Unmatched Rows Using tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to join two tibbles. The first tibble includes the national averages of several categories, and is shown here:

`test_tbl1`: National averages per category:

[image]

The second tibble includes state averages of the same categories, if they exist. For example, here are AL and AK counts per category:

`test_tbl2`: State averages per category:

[image]

I'd like to join these two such that the national average for each category shows up per state, even if the state has no value for a category. Note that states AK and AL have no values for category O.

This seems like a job for the `_join()` functions in R. I've tried left, right, and full. They all return the same thing, which looks like and inner join. If a state has a row for category O, then it is included in the result set.

Here's the code:

```
 test_tbl3 <- test_tbl1 %>% full_join(test_tbl2)
```

The tibbles are joined on the `idx` column.

Here's the result:

`test_tbl3`: No unmatched rows are shown:

[image]

**Desired Result**

I'd like to have the same result as shown in the second image, but each state that did not have an existing value for category "O" (the idx column) would have a row with the national average. Like this...

```
idx natl_count natl_avg state  idx  n
  O   47        0.92     AK    NA   NA
  O   47        0.92     AL    NA   NA
  O   47        0.92     AR    NA   NA
  O   47        0.92     AZ    NA   NA
```

These states do not have a value for "O" but should still contain a row for the national average. In relational database SQL, this is a no-brainer. I may just not understand how joins work in R.

Comment: Can you clarify what your final result should look like from your example? Did you want missing data `NA` for states with absent categories (like `NA` for "n" if category "O" in the example)? It would help to show a final "desired" data table of what you hope to have in the end, based on your example.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Images are not helpful. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got it. Rather than using joins to create rows for unmatched records, I used more of a brute force approach by iterating the data, finding those states with no values for any row in the national data set, then creating and appending rows to the state data set with national values (and zeroes for state counts). Surely there's a more elegant approach, but it'll do the trick. Still open to suggestions for a better mouse trap.

```r
# tbl_by_idx    has all the values at the national level, same as content in figure 1
# tbl_by_st_idx has all the values at the state level, same as content in figure 2

# Get a distinct set of all states 
states <- tbl_by_st_idx %>% distinct(state) 

# Iterate the national records, find which states have a value for idx 
for (val in tbl_by_idx$idx) {
  curr_idx <- tbl_by_st_idx %>% 
    filter(idx == val) %>% 
    distinct(state)
  # Perform an anti-join against states to extract states no value for idx
  # Merge with tbl_by_idx filtered by idx
  tbl_idx_zero <- merge(
      anti_join(states, curr_idx), 
      tbl_by_idx %>% filter(idx == val)
      ) %>% 
    mutate (st_count = 0)
  # If the merge produces records, append it to the state values
  if (nrow(tbl_idx_zero) > 0) { 
    tbl_by_st_idx <- rbind(tbl_idx_zero, tbl_by_st_idx)
    }
  }
```